# Wildcard nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, subdomain, url-rewriting, wildcard

I suspect this will be quite simple, yet I can't seem to get my head around the nginx rewrite system. Hopefully someone could chime in and help me out?

Quite simply, I need..

```
http://example.com/?c=foo
```

to to be rewritten to...

```
http://foo.example.com
```

Thank-you in advance if you've taken pitty on this nginx noob :)
I'll keep having a go at this, and in the unlikely event I hit a 'eureka' moment, I'll update this to help anyone who's having/will ever have this similar 'problem'.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is impossible to make internal redirect to other domain in Nginx. But there are two available solutions:

1) Simple: make redirect to specified address. Example:

```
if ( $arg_c ) {
    rewrite ^ http://$arg_c.example.com;
}
```

2) Complex: if you use Nginx as a proxy between php-fpm, apache or something else, you could set the Host header in this way:: 
    set $new_host example.com;

```
if ( $arg_c) {
    set $new_host $arg_c.example.com;
}
```

and pass it as a parameter:

```
proxy_set_header   Host $new_host;
```